# Is it possible to create a concept that is only a lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20, c++-concepts

Since C++ 20, the concepts have been released to constrain templates and auto.

I wanted to create a concept that only defines a lambda, is it possible?

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept lambda = /* ... */ ;
```

And then I could apply like this:

```cpp
int add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}

lambda auto func1 = []{ return 5; }; // constrain satisfied
lambda auto func2 = add; // constrain unsatisfied, compilation error.
```

Comment: "*I wanted to create a concept that only defines a lambda*" This is not a thing you should *want* to do. Lambdas in C++ are not magical things; they're just classes that have an `operator()` overload. That's it. There is no reason to guard a template instantiation *specifically* against non-lambda types. There is no reason to force a user to employ a lambda specifically instead of just taking any callable object. And we already have ways of asking whether a value of a type is callable.

Comment: Yeah, I'm having a hard time envisioning the use case for this. Surely there's nothing special about lambdas, all you need is a callable, whether that's a lambda, function address (maybe), or something back from `std::bind()`? I don't think a `requires` clause is going to be able to differentiate.

Comment: What is the actual problem you need to solve? Why do you need a concept like that?

Comment: I just want to achieve having a concept that only defines a lambda if it is POSSIBLE. If not, that is okay, since they are just objects of class having overloaded call operators.

Comment: Not possible in general, because lambdas have nothing special about them compared to user-defined classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the type name of `T` at compiler time, and then determine whether it contains the mangled name of lambda, which starts with `<lambda` in gcc  and `(lambda`  in clang:

Although it is feasible, it is actually not recommended.

```
#include <string_view>

template <typename T>
consteval bool is_lambda() {
  std::string_view name = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
  auto pos = name.find("T = ");
  name.remove_prefix(pos + 4);
  if (pos = name.rfind("::"); pos != name.npos) 
    name.remove_prefix(pos + 2);
#ifdef __clang__
  return name.starts_with("(lambda");
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
  return name.starts_with("<lambda");
#endif
}

template <class T>
concept lambda = is_lambda<T>();
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/j4GTPPbe1)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you'd want this, but the closest I can think of is this:

```
template <typename T>
concept lambda = requires { &T::operator(); };
```

[Compiler Explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/hjTaxvMxE)

Basically, this requires that `T` has a call operator. This works because that's how lambdas are implemented: they give you an object whose type has a compiler generated `operator()`.

However, this concept accepts things that are not lambdas, namely user defined structs that have call operators, such as `std::function`, `std::bind`, `std::reference_wrapper`, etc. Thus, this concept accepts basically all callables which are not function pointers, which is a strange categorization of C++ function objects.

Comment: This doesn't work if the lambda is templated (or if `operator()` is overloaded, which you can't do with a lambda).